# How to establish One to Many relationship using Apex

Tags: lookup, master-detail

I am building an app which reads information from an external API and then populates data in my App for further processing. I have two kinds of custom objects for this. First kind (e.g., Profile) stores all the retrieved information. And second kind (e.g., Summary) stores the derived information.

Summary also needs to have a lookup for more than on Profile objects so I have created a master-detail relationship between Summary-Profile. I am able to connect one Profile object to Summary as follows, but how can I do this for more than one profiles.

```
public Profile__c addProfile(Map<String, Object> profile){
    Profile__c obj = new Profile__c();
    obj.Zip__c = (String)profile.get('Zip');
    insert obj;
    return obj;
}

public PageReference doInsert() {
    Summary__c objdlt = new Summary__c();
    objdlt.Name__c = nameVal;

    # Get json response from external API

    Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(json_response);

    Map<String, Object> profile = (Map<String, Object>)m.get('Profile');

    # THIS LINE
    objdlt.Profile__c = addProfile(basic_profile).Id;
    insert objdlt; 

    pagereference ref = new pagereference(redirect_page);
    ref.setredirect(true);
    return ref;
}
```

Comment: Can you post that JSON?

Answer (score 1):

`#` marks a line as a comment in Python. It will cause syntax errors in Apex, where you need to use C/Java style `/* ... */` or `//` line comments.

Here, you have backed yourself into a corner by building a method `addProfile()` that performs DML but not storing its return value in an sObject variable.

You don't want to add the Profile more than once by calling the method repeatedly, so what you need to do is

```
Profile__c p = addProfile(basic_profile).Id;
```

then

```
objdlt.Profile__c  = p.Id;
```

You may repeat the latter pattern for as many `Summary__c` objects as you need. Note, however, that you should accumulate these objects in a `List<Summary__c>` and insert them in a single bulk operation.